# RestSharp http statut code and response statut of 0 "Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)"

Tags: c#, mongodb, rest, xamarin

I'm trying to query data on my mlab mongodb database with their rest api but I can't get it to work.

To makehttp rest requests in my Xamarin application I'm using restSharp, I tried many times but I always get an empty answer, not event the header so I really don't know where the problem is coming from.

Here is my code:

```
 class HttpDataHandler
{
    static String stream = null;
    public String GetHttpData(String collection)
    {
        var uri = "https://api.mlab.com";

        var client = new RestClient(uri);

        var request = new RestRequest("api/1/databases/{db}/collections/{coll}" , Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("apiKey", Common.API_KEY); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
        request.AddUrlSegment("db", Common.DB_NAME);
        request.AddUrlSegment("coll", collection);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            System.Console.WriteLine(response.Content); // raw content as string
        else
            System.Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription + " " + response.ResponseUri+" "+ response.StatusCode);

       return stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which platform are you using? Is the `response` variable null or is the `StatusCode` set?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2017, no the `response` variable is not null and `StatusCode` is set to 0;

Comment: I meant iOS, Android, UWP as platform. Is the `ErrorMessage` property of the `response` set?

Comment: Oh yes sorry i'm using Android, yes I have `"Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mLab is using TLS1.2. Changing the SSL/TLS implementation of your Android project from `Default` to `Native TLS 1.2+` most likely will fix the issue.

See [the HttpClient Stack and SSL/TLS documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/http-stack/) for an extensive explanation on these 2 combo-boxes that are provided in Xamarin Android projects.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim it was the problem